# Auto-fit a svg file to window?

Tags: java, svg, fit-framework

I have a svg file and it's displaying all right. Now, I want it to fit the window but I couldn't find something like `.AutofitToWindow`. I can't change the svg file. Please help.

Comment: Are you using Batik and JSVGCanvas? If you are using JSVGCanvas, are you have a problem with Swing layout, such that the JSVGCanvas instance must fill the JWindow instance; or are you have a problem with SVG layout, such that JSVGCanvas fills its container, but the rendered SVG does not fill the JSVGCanvas?

Answer (score 0):

Put whatever component renders the SVG into the `CENTER` constraint of a `BorderLayout`.